# What is $\lim_{x\to0}(x\Gamma(x))^\frac1x$?

Tags: calculus, limits, gamma-function

Finding this type of limit can be seen in quite a few calculus problems.
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n!^\frac1n
$$
And also easily solved by Stirling approximation, or ect.

Then, what will happen when $n$ goes to zero? We cannot define a factorial of non-integer, so I'll use $x\Gamma(x)$ instead of $x!$. The values of these two are exactly the same when $x$ is natural number.

So, what would be the limit of this?
$$
\lim_{x\to0}(x\Gamma(x))^\frac1x
$$

Comment: Note that $x\Gamma (x) = \Gamma (x + 1) = 1 - \gamma x + \mathcal{O}(x^2 )$. Thus, $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} (1 - \gamma x + \mathcal{O}(x^2 ))^{1/x}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left( {1 + \frac{{ - \gamma }}{n} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right)} \right)^n  = e^{ - \gamma } .
$$

Comment: Oh, thanks @Gary ! But I didn't understand that $\Gamma'(0)=-\gamma$, so I felt it was not reasonable to put that fact in my proof. Your answer is much simpler!

Comment: Actually, Gary uses $\Gamma'(1)=-\gamma$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gamma function has many forms, and I'll use Weierstrass form like below instead of familiar integral form $\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt$.
$$
\Gamma(z)=\frac{e^{-\gamma z}}z\prod_1^\infty\frac{e^\frac zn}{1+\frac zn}
$$
Then, our $(x\Gamma(x))^\frac1x$ changes into $e^{-\gamma}\prod_1^\infty\frac{e^\frac1n}{\left(1+\frac xn\right)^\frac1x}$.

Since $\lim_{x\to0}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^\frac1x=e^\frac1n$, so...

$$
\lim_{x\to0}(x\Gamma(x))^\frac1x=\lim_{x\to0}e^{-\gamma}\prod_1^\infty\frac{e^\frac1n}{\left(1+\frac xn\right)^\frac1x}=e^{-\gamma}
$$
($\gamma$ is Euler-Mascheroni constant.)

Comment: Right answer.  But explain the interchange $\lim_{x\to 0}\prod_{n=1}^\infty \dots = \prod_{n=1}^\infty\lim_{x\to 0}\dots$

Comment: @GEdgar, Can it be explained by $\forall N\in\Bbb N, \lim\prod_1^N=1$, so $\lim\prod_1^\infty=1$?

Comment: @Nightflight No, you need to demonstrate, for example, uniform convergence.